# Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a database there have two table tutorials and districts tutorials has a one to one relation with district.Here in tutorials add page I am trying to get districts list.

So I have Coded in TutorialsController in add methods below code

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Tutorial->create();
            if ($this->Tutorial->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutorial has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutorial could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $districts = $this->Tutorial->District->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('districts'));
    }
```

I have ensured

```
var $uses = array('Tutorial','District');
```

Relation code in Tutorial

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Districts' => array(
            'className' => 'Districts',
            'foreignKey' => 'districts_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Still I am facing error Call to a member function find() on a non-object in line code

```
$districts = $this->Tutorial->District->find('list');
```

I have used `var $uses = array('Tutorial','District');`

Why still this error is giving ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `var $uses = array('Tutorial','District');`(its unnecessary while models are associated) and edit as-

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'District' => array( // remove 's'
            'className' => 'Districts',
            'foreignKey' => 'districts_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Comment: you can remove everything and just have `public $belongsTo = array('District')` (unless districtS_id isn't a typo - inwhich case that array key should stay).